# ManyToMany with composite key with api-platform

Tags: api, many-to-many, entity, many-to-one, api-platform.com

I am using Api Platform.
I have two entities Player and Team and one entity PlayerHasTeam to represent in the database the date on which the player joined a team.

This is my PlayerHasTeam entity :

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "post"
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "put",
 *         "delete"
 *     }
 * )

 * @ORM\Table(name="playerHasTeam")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PlayerHasTeam
{
/** 
 * @var Player
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Player", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="idPlayer", name="idPlayer", nullable=false)
 * 
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $player;


/**
 * @var Team
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Team", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="idTeam", name="idTeam", nullable=false)
 * 
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $team;

/**
 * @var DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="joinedAt", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $joinedAt;



(Getters and Setters)
```

The problem is the following, I need to do GET, PUT and DELETE request on this Composite Entity.
Api-platform defines the following routes :
    **GET** /player_has_teams
    **POST** /player_has_teams
    **GET** /player_has_teams/{id}
    **PUT** /player_has_teams/{id}
    **DELETE** /player_has_teams/{id}

I cannot use the 3 last because I don't have a generated id.
I want to do my requests with a route like **/player_has_teams/{idPlayer}/{idTeam}**

It seems that api-platform does not handle this case.

Do you have any suggestions ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found a solution.
I just have to call my route like this
**GET** /player_has_teams/player=1;team=1
**PUT** /player_has_teams/player=1;team=1